# What algorithm(s) do numpy and scipy use to calculate matrix inverses?

Tags: matrix, scipy, numpy, inverse

I am solving differential equations that require inverting dense square matrices, and I wanted to know what algorithm(s) do numpy and scipy use to calculate matrix inverses?

Comment: By way of comparison, there are `R` libraries which use the Crout method and the Doolittle method of LU decomposition.

Answer (score 11):

Documentation to `numpy.linalg.inv` and `scipy.linalg.inv` does not mention the algorithm used.

Judging from the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L493), `numpy.linalg.inv` calls a C++ [wrapper](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.cpp#L1809) to LAPACK `gesv` subroutine, which uses LU decomposition (more specifically, LU with partial pivoting, $A = P L U$), and `scipy.linalg.inv` [uses](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.4/scipy/linalg/_basic.py#L903) slightly more low-level LAPACK computational routines, performing the same decomposition.

Comment: Note that there are various different ways to obtain an inverse from the PLU decomposition of a matrix, so even the step following PLU is not completely trivial. Higham's "Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms" has an entire chapter on it.

Comment: This is also the default algorithm choice for numpy and scipy's `solve` function, so that can be used instead for solving linear systems.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, they don't take matrix inverses. They perform linear solves. Typically this is done via LU factorization.

Comment: Sure they do compute inverses, if you call [`inv`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.inv.html).

Comment: Sure, but don't do that.

Comment: I was sure that the documentation page for `numpy.linalg.inv` had a comment recommending to use `numpy.linalg.solve` instead whenever possible, but apparently I remember wrong.

Comment: They use the exact same algorithm under the hood but obviously less work is done in using `solve` compared to `inv` because you just do fewer operations.